# Get ID after click

Tags: jquery, url, get, onclick

I have a set of links:

```
<a href='#?idCountry=" + MX + "' class='SendData'>"Mexico"</a>
<a href='#?idCountry=" + EU + "' class='SendData'>"USA"</a>
<a href='#?idCountry=" + CO + "' class='SendData'>"Colombia"</a>
```

Then I use the following function to get the value clicked from the URL:

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
if (results==null){
return null;
}else{
return results[1] || 0;
}   
}
```

...And I'm using the click() event to get the clicked value:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".SendData").click( function(e) {

    var idCountry = $.urlParam('idCountry');  
    console.log(idCountry);
    ....other actions with idCountry
}
});
```

It works but only after a second clic, I supose because it first excecute query function and after that it change the URL value.

What options I have to get the **idCountry** after click the link??

Thank you.

Comment: What does the actual HTML look like in the browser (not your server template language)?  This isn't valid HTML: `<a href='#?idCountry=" + MX + "' class='SendData'>"Mexico"</a>`.

Comment: in the server is: <a href='myPage.html?idCountry=MX' class='SendData'>"Mexico"</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following (untestet):

```
$.urlParam = function(url, name){
var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(url);
if (results==null){
return null;
}else{
return results[1] || 0;
}   
}


$(document).ready(function() {
$(".SendData").click( function(e) {

    var idCountry = $.urlParam($(this).prop('href'),'idCountry');  
    console.log(idCountry);
    ....other actions with idCountry
}
});
```